# Horror movie where a guy loses his hand after putting his hand INTO a mirror?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I only vaguely remember a scene from a horror movie, where near the climax, the characters are trying to escape from the haunted house and during the escape, one of the ghosts (who is inside a mirror) tempts a guy into coming back. The guy gets hypnotized (kinda) and puts his hand INTO the mirror. The other characters try to pull him out and succeed but he ends up losing his hand in the process. The guy survives.

Other small details I THINK I remember, which I'm not sure of:

- the guy who loses his hand was overweight
- the ghost in the mirror was his mother (or at least had the appearance of his mother)
- the movie might be from the early 90s. It looked "clean" quality-wise, like an american film, and I think it used CGI for the mirror effect, where it looked like the mirror was liquid when the guy grabbed inside of it.
- the characters look over a grave near the end (along with the guy who lost his hand)

Does anybody know the name of that movie?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all I remember :( The memories are pretty blurry, but the movie couldn't have been too old, maybe early 90s?

Comment: Added some more details that might help, but that's really all I have XD

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtuI0LbA1Q4

Comment: That's nothing like what I described... and no, that's definitely not it.

Comment: Jesus Christ, one week and still no answer... Am I really the only one remembering the movie (somewhat)? I guess it wasn't a well-received movie then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It kinda sounds like Stephen King's *Rose Red*. There was a scene near the end of the final part in the miniseries when they where escaping the mansion when a character that had recently died turned into a ghost and was attempting to pull the man into the mirror and a guy manages to help him get free.

Comment: Wow, I did not expect to get an answer after all this time. Seems like you hit the nail on the head. :D Although, it seems the guy who was almost pulled into the mirror didn't really lose his hand as I remembered... he just has this glove on. Not sure what is up with that, but everything else is spot on. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, I'm just glad that I could answer your question and get it right.

Comment: @noClue - we often find, especially when remembering something from 20 years ago, that the details we remember aren't quite right. I've done it myself on several questions. That's why every man needs a wife around, 'cuz they take notes.