# Horror film involving a haunted house and a girl with powers who makes giant rocks fall into a house

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

The film is about a haunted house. In it appears a girl with powers. There is a scene where the dog next door is barking at her and she makes giant rocks fall into the house.

The movie ends with people escaping from the haunted house and the girl destroys the haunted house with her powers.
There are ghosts too.

This was a live-action film. I saw it on TV around 2005-2006, so the film release would be before that year.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a live-action movie or an animated movie?  Where did you see it?

Comment: Hi! Thanks. 
Live-action. 
I saw on TV. About 2005-2006. So film release would be before that year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horror movie where a guy loses his hand after putting his hand INTO a mirror?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147239/horror-movie-where-a-guy-loses-his-hand-after-putting-his-hand-into-a-mirror)

Comment: @DavidW Bro, why the hell is my nearly 7 YEAR OLD question now considered a duplicate of this question that was asked a week ago? Did someone swap the questions or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is Stephen King's ***[Rose Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_Red_(miniseries))*** (2002).

> Dr. Joyce Reardon, an unorthodox university psychology professor, leads a team of psychics to the massive and antiquated Seattle mansion known as Rose Red in an attempt to record data that would constitute scientific proof of paranormal phenomena. The mansion is publicly thought to be haunted, as at least 23 people have either disappeared or died there and the interior of the house appears to change or increase in size, yet only from the inside. Reardon's team awakens the evil spirit possessing the house, leading to several deaths and the revelation of the mansion's deadly secrets.

This three-part, roughly four-hour-long miniseries centres on a haunted mansion known as Rose Red, which is investigated by a college professor and six psychics she's hired to help her obtain proof of the existence of paranormal phenomena.

Each of the psychics has a speciality, such as psychometry, precognition, postcognition and automatic writing. The most powerful of them by far is an autistic 15-year-old named Annie Wheaton, whose telekinetic powers can turn water into ice and cause boulders to fall from the sky.

In the opening scene of the miniseries -- which is set ten years before the main story -- a five-year-old Annie causes boulders to fall onto the house of an elderly couple living across the street from her, whose dog had previously bitten her. We don't see or hear the dog in that scene, as it'd been put down already, but a later flashback shows the incident during which Annie was bitten, and the dog did bark at her in that scene.

In the climax of the miniseries, Annie similarly causes boulders to fall onto the Rose Red mansion, which is haunted by the ghosts of people who've died there.

The whole series is currently uploaded to YouTube, but I'll just link a trailer here.